# SQL database Username contains Special Chars

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, special-characters

I have a Spring Boot application with SQL Server. My database username contains a @ symbol.
eg: username@pc.com. At runtime, it's considered @pc.com as a server and throwing "cannot open pc.com server". I have tried below options for fixing it, but no luck.

```
username%40pc.com
username\\@pc.com
"\"username@pc.com\""
```

Comment: I am absolutely sure you definitely need to have a special symbol in username. Go on this way

Comment: ok, not sure how to handle the special chars within the database username. Right now "username" taking as user name and "pc.com" considering as the server name.